# Linux Bash -- how to know which directory I really am in with symlinks?

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

suppose I have a symlink chain A -> B -> C

when I type pwd, it could show me in A, B, or C depending how I get here.

How do I show the physical directory address, i.e. not represented by any symlinks?

Comment: Related: [Strange difference between pwd and /bin/pwd](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145479/80216).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
pwd -P
```

It works for me (using zsh).

```
$ ls -l

  drwxrwxr-x 2 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 4096 Aug 28 10:14 a 
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx    1 Aug 28 10:15 b -> a

$ cd b

$ pwd
  /home/xxxxxxx/temp/b

$ pwd -P
  /home/xxxxxxx/temp/a
```

Answer (score 1):

- The command you are searching for is probably `**pwd -P**`.
- You can find useful even `readlink -f`. (`man info coreutils readlink`).
- In some system you can find [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)
  that you can invoke not only on the current directory
  `realpath .`
  but even to any other file `realpath \my\long\path\file.ext`

---

Your `shell` usually has a *built-in* *pwd* command that is used instead of `/bin/pwd`.
If you write in a shell `type pwd` it will answer if your shell provide you a built-in version.

For the correct help you can refer to

- `man pwd` usually for the `\bin\pwd` command
- `man bash` and after search for `pwd` for the built in version.
- `man <TheShellName>` for the other shells (zsh,csh,tcsh...)

From `man bash` e.g. you can read

> **pwd** [-LP]
>
> Print  the absolute pathname of the current working directory.  **The pathname printed contains no symbolic links if the -P  option is supplied** or the *-o physical option to the set builtin command is enabled*.  If the -L option is used, the pathname printed may
> contain  symbolic  links.   The  return status is 0 unless an error occurs while reading the name of the current directory or an invalid option is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readlink (if available in your distro) from the current directory:

```
$ readlink -f .
```

or with a full path:

```
$ readlink -f /my-dir/with-some-link
```

rhel/centos provide it in coreutils pkg.
hth.